# CMIS 1.1 creating new type by using Workbench

Tags: cmis

I've tried to create new cmis type from the xml file that I had created by using export cmis:document.

Now when try to create new type, comes the error that the "parentTypeId" is not defined. I have added the "parentTypeId", but the same error message still comes :-(
here is my XML

```
<cmis:type ...
<cmis:id>cmis:testDocumentId</cmis:id>
    <cmis:parentTypeId>cmis:item</cmis:parentTypeId>
    <cmis:localName>TestLocalDocName</cmis:localName>
    <cmis:localNamespace>http://test.local/jcr</cmis:localNamespace>
    <cmis:displayName>TestDocument</cmis:displayName>
    <cmis:queryName>cmis:document</cmis:queryName>
    <cmis:description>This is TEST Document</cmis:description>
    <cmis:baseId>cmis:document</cmis:baseId>
    <cmis:creatable>true</cmis:creatable>
    <cmis:fileable>true</cmis:fileable>
    <cmis:queryable>true</cmis:queryable>
    <cmis:fulltextIndexed>false</cmis:fulltextIndexed>
    <cmis:includedInSupertypeQuery>true</cmis:includedInSupertypeQuery>
    <cmis:controllablePolicy>false</cmis:controllablePolicy>
    <cmis:controllableACL>false</cmis:controllableACL>
    <cmis:propertyIdDefinition>
```

Comment: What back-end CMIS server are you using? Maybe it doesn't support type mutability?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is misleading (and has already been fixed).
The missing tag is `<cmis:parentId>`.

The cmis:document type does not have this tag because cmis:document is a base type and has no parent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have forgotten to mention that  I'm using mode shape 5.1 and they are not using the latest version of CMIS.